# Stripes: Refresh Page

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, stripes

I am working on stripes. the problem I am facing is when i submit a form it calls a web service and add the record and gives the success message. But if I refresh my success message page then it will again submit my form, calls the web service and add the record. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect after the successful POST. That's the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

In Stripes, redirecting consists in returning a [RedirectResolution](https://stripesframework.ci.cloudbees.com/job/Stripes%201.6.0/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/RedirectResolution.html) from your ActionBean method.

Comment: and how should I do this?

Comment: so instead of using ForwardResolution I should use Redirect? what benefit it could make then?

Comment: The benefit that refreshing will now re-send a GET request and not the POST used to add the record. Have you clicked on the link I gave you? It explains the benefit you get from this pattern, and the main one is to avoid the problem you want to avoid.

Comment: i have applied it on my action bean but when the success message is displayed and i refresh page then every thing disappears and only success message remains displayed.

Comment: Where do you redirect to? You should redirect to the action which displays what you want to display after the addition of the record. Not to a JSP or to the action adding the record. Have you read the article I linked to?